# how to remove the white space between the image and the next column?

Tags: white-space

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{0.75\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{rp{27em}}
\textbf{SRC}: & caption1 \\
\textbf{Prototypa}: & caption2 \\
\textbf{MODEL2}: & caption3 \\
\textbf{MODEL3}: & caption4 \\
\textbf{MODEL4}: & caption5 \\

\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

 \caption{ Examples how the model behaves.}
 \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{A.jpg}`

Comment: Subtable resets \textwidth to its width, just like a minipage with `\def\@captype{subtable}`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change

```
\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
```

to

```
\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.jpg}
\end{subtable}%
```

and also change

```
\begin{tabular}{rp{27em}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{27em}}
```

The `@{}` particle instructs LaTeX not to insert any whitespace padding at the left-hand edge of the `tabular` environment.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{subtable}{0.22\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{A.jpg}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{0.75\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}rp{27em}}
\textbf{SRC}: & caption1 \\
\textbf{Prototypa}: & caption2 \\
\textbf{MODEL2}: & caption3 \\
\textbf{MODEL3}: & caption4 \\
\textbf{MODEL4}: & caption5 \\

\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

 \caption{ Examples how the model behaves.}
 \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```